# checking if password contains dictionary words

Tags: regex

I have to check whether a random password i generated contains any dictionary words. For this I am using grep into /usr/share/dict/words

How Can I use grep so as to return me all matches for not only entire expression but also any part of the expression.

example:

grep "foobar" foo

where foo contains text foo should give me a match

Comment: Sure you want to do that?  `/usr/share/dict/words` includes words like `a`, so you'd match on every password containing the letter `a`.  Have you considered [CrackLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cracklib/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo foo | grep -c --file=/usr/share/dict/words
```

would yield `1` when there is a match and `0` when there isn't.